# Jpeg to Word Conversion

Tags: text, ms-word, jpeg, rtf

Is there any open source software that will convert jpeg to word or rtf or just plain text

Comment: Are you talking about OCR? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment on your question, it sounds as if you're looking for OCR (Optical Character Recognition) software.  You could look at using [Tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) -- it requires a TIFF file as input and outputs plain text, but you can easily call it from a script that converts the input from JPEG to TIFF and the output from plain text to whatever you want.  Another option to consider would be [GOCR](http://jocr.sourceforge.net).